# How to use sed command to modify a file's entry line by line in shell script?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, sed

This is my `file1`:

```
#$BQ
#{ VOL       @home    }
#database    daba
#relation    tcdeatid
#copy           1
#{ version        0 }
#opendb
#clear
#.lruno := 72
#.infno := 1
#.tid.noel := 101
#.tid.info := 64
#.tid.setnr := 1225              <--- (1225 number will be changed)
#.typeidm := 1
#.sourcetable := 2
#writedb     
#clear
#.lruno := 72
#.infno := 205
#.tid.noel := 101
#.tid.info := 76
#.tid.setnr := 5625              <--- (5625 number will be changed)
#.typeidm := 1
#.sourcetable := 2
#writedb
#$EOJ
```

In `file2`, I have the correct entries:

```
#.tid.info := 3345              <--- (I want to put this number in file1 in place of 64)
#.tid.setnr := 1254              <--- (I want to put this number in file1 in place of 1225)
#.tid.info := 5567              <--- (I want to put this number in file1 in place of 76)
#.tid.setnr := 9056              <--- (I want to put this number in file1 in place of 5625)
```

I want to make changes in `file1`, directed by data from `file2`.

I have tried
`sed "s/tid.setnr := 1225/tid.setnr := 1254/g" file1 > modified_file1`

**But instead of doing it manually, I want my script to read the new `tid.info` and `tid.setnr` values from `file2` and modify the respective lines in `file1`. 
The first line in `file2` should replace the entire first line in `file1`
that contains `tid.info`, the second line in `file2` should replace
the second line in `file1` that contains `tid.setnr`, and so on.**

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange.  Your question sounds a little like this to me: "I have an apple and an orange, and I want magic to happen, resulting in a banana, or something like that."  Please *explain* a bit more about the operation you are trying to perform.  For example, will file2 always be a list of `tid.setnr` values and nothing else, or can file2 contain any of the tags that are in file1?  Can file2 contain tags that aren't in file1?  (If so, how do you know where to put them?)  What if file1 has three `tid.setnr` values and file2 has only two?  … … … … … … … …  Also, what have you tried?

Comment: P.S. Please [edit] your question to add details and make it clearer; do not respond to my comment with more comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this with `sed` is to generate a `sed` script:

```
tmpfile=/tmp/Nainita.$$
exec 3< file2
grep -n "tid\.setnr" file1 | while IFS=: read n junk
do
        IFS= read -r line <&3  ||  break
        printf "%sc%s\n%s\n" "$n" '\' "$line"
done > "$tmpfile"
exec 3<&-
sed -f "$tmpfile" file1 > modified_file1
rm -f "$tmpfile"
```

- `exec 3< file2` opens `file2` for reading on file descriptor 3.
- The `grep -n` finds the lines in `file1` that contain `tid.setnr`,
  by line number.  This gets piped into a `while` loop.
- `while IFS=: read n junk`

  - `while … read …` means read a line at a time, repeatedly,
    as long as there is information to read
    (i.e., stopping when it reaches the end of the data).
  - `IFS=: read n junk` means read everything up to the first `:`
    (which will be the line number from `grep -n`) into `n`,
    and the rest of the line (the old `tid.setnr` data line) into `junk`,
    which we ignore, because we don’t care about it.
- `IFS= read -r line <&3` reads a line from file descriptor 3 (`file2`),
  doing everything that we know how to do to tell the shell not to mangle it,
  and put it into a variable called `line`.
- `…  ||  break` says, if the above `read` fails
  (presumably due to end of file), break out of the loop.
- The `printf` writes a `sed` **c**hange command,
  addressed to line number `n`, saying that that line should be replaced
  with the content on the `line` variable.
- `done > "$tmpfile"` marks the end of the `while` loop
  and specifies that the standard output of the entire loop is `$tmpfile`. 
  This will end up looking like this:

  ```
  13c\
  #.tid.setnr := 1254
  22c\
  #.tid.setnr := 9056
  ```

  - Note that the `while` loop terminates
    as soon as it gets an EOF from either input. 
    Therefore, if `file1` has more `tid.setnr` lines than `file2`,
    the extra ones will go unchanged
    (i.e., `c` commands for them will not be generated). 
    Similarly, if `file2` has more `tid.setnr` lines than `file1`,
    the extra ones will be ignored. 
    Unfortunately, this discrepancy will not be reported,
    although adding that capability would not be very hard.
- `exec 3<&-` closes file descriptor 3.
- `sed -f "$tmpfile" file1 > modified_file1` runs `sed` on `file1`,
  reading commands from `$tmpfile` and writing output to `modified_file1`.

This should do what you want.  Obviously, change the filenames if you want. 
You should run this “as is” once, and then look at the `modified_file1` file
(or simply change the `sed` command not to redirect its output,
so it writes to the screen) and verify that the output is what you want. 
Then you can change the `sed` command to `sed -i` to edit `file1` in place
(if that’s what you want to do).

If the `sed` command gives an error like “Too many line numbers”,
try splitting the script file (`$tmpfile`) into smaller files. 
I suggest starting with a size under 100 commands;
e.g., 90 commands, which is 180 lines, since each command is two lines. 
You can do this manually, with a text editor<sup>1</sup>,
but there’s a tool written specifically for this job. 
It is, intuitively, called `split`.  The command

```
split --lines=180 "$tmpfile"
```

will split the script into files in the current directory
called `xaa`, `xab`, `xac`, ….  The first *n*−1 will be 180 lines long;
the last one will be whatever it needs to be (≤ 180) to make up the total. 
For example, if you have 500 instances of `tid.setnr`,
then your script will be 1000 lines long, and you will get six `x` files —
`xaa`, `xab`, `xac`, `xad`, and `xae` will each have 180 lines,
and `xaf` will have 100.  Now do

```
sed -f xaa file1 > modified_file1aa
```

If you still get “Too many line numbers”,
go back and try it again with a smaller number of `--lines`. 
If it doesn’t report an error, look at `modified_file1aa` and see
whether it looks like the first 90 `tid.setnr` lines have been changed. 
If it looks OK, then do

```
sed -f xab modified_file1aa > modified_file1ab
sed -f xac modified_file1ab > modified_file1ac
sed -f xad modified_file1ac > modified_file1ad
sed -f xae modified_file1ad > modified_file1ae
sed -f xaf modified_file1ae > modified_file1af
```

`modified_file1af` is now your final `modified_file1`.

If you want to <strike>play</strike> experiment, you can

- Try larger numbers of `--lines` until you find out what the maximum is.
- Try

  ```
  sed -f xaa -f xab -f xac -f xad -f xae -f xaf file1 > modified_file1_test
  ```

  but that probably won’t work.
- If you do the above experiments, I encourage you to tell us the results.

If you only need to do this one time, you’re done. 
But, if you need to do this repeatedly,
change the last two lines of the code block at the top of this answer to

```
split --lines=180 "$tmpfile"            <--- (Using a number that works for you, of course)
cp file1 modified_file1
for f in x*
do
        sed -i -f "$f" modified_file1
done
rm -f "$tmpfile" x*
```

As I mentioned earlier,
the `-i` option tells `sed` to edit the specified file in place
(i.e., write the changes back out to the input file).  Or, even simpler,

```
split --lines=180 "$tmpfile"
for f in x*
do
        sed -i -f "$f" file1
done
rm -f "$tmpfile" x*
```

if you don’t need to keep your original `file1` intact.

Note that the usage synopsis for `split` is

```
split [OPTION]… [INPUT [PREFIX]]
```

and its default behavior is to create files called `PREFIXaa`, `PREFIXab`, `PREFIXac`, etc. 
In other words, the default *`PREFIX`* is `x`. 
If you might have other files whose names begin with `x`,
you should define `prefix` to be something that will be unique
(e.g., `prefix=Nainita.$$.` or `prefix=/tmp/Nainita.$$.`)
and then change the above to

```
split --lines=180 "$tmpfile" "$prefix"
for f in "$prefix"*
do
        sed -i -f "$f" file1
done
rm -f "$tmpfile" "$prefix"*
```

______
<sup>1</sup> If you’re a glutton for punishment,
you ***could*** do it with `sed` — but why play with fire?

Comment: Many thanks for your reply... I will be in touch after implementing your solution... But I have a question.... I have understand what you said... but I have to load e\with the corrected value of file 1 into the database without changing its file format... If I try your solution, then is the file format remain unchanged?

Comment: I don't understand your concern.  The output (`modified_file1`) will be exactly the same as `file1` in lines 1-12, 14-21, and 23-28 (`file1` is 28 lines long).  Line 13 of `modified_file1` will be line 1 from `file2`.  Line 22 of `modified_file1` will be line 2 from `file2`.

Comment: Yes... thanks again... it is cleared now...

Comment: I think this might be unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: My comment wasn't meant to remark on *length* or *breadth* but *complexity*. The problem with this answer - and the reason I wrote mine - is that you're defying the basic principles of `sed`'s design just to write its script. That's what makes it complicated. It's a stream editor - it's easier to use with streams. Anyway, doing it this way doesn't fit `sed` well - which is why you have to shoehorn it in - but `ed` or `ex` could do the whole thing in similar fashion with a few keystrokes. Because I trade i/o en-route, my answer is both clear *and* brief. Learning how took a long while, though.

Comment: Scott I have implemented your solution in my system.. It's working . But there is a small problem, when I tried it for two tid.setnr its working.. But in my another file there are 500 tid.setnr for correction. So when I am going to correct 500 entries by using this commad, sed -f "$tmpfile" file1 > modified_file1 , It's telling "Too many line numbers" . Please help

Comment: I am using Solaris 8 (version 5.8).... Is there any limitations of line numbers which is 256? I am stucked in the last step (sed -f "$tmpfile" file1 > modified_file1)
It is not generating modified_file1 due to "Too many line numbers" error

Comment: @Nainita: My first suggestion is that you try Cyrus’s answer — the modified one, from the comment, first, because it’s simpler; then, if that fails, try the one from his main answer.  (Add `> modified_file1` to the end either way.)  But his answer requires the use of GNU sed; I don’t know whether that’s available on Solaris.  My second suggestion is more complicated; I have added it to my answer.

Comment: Yes I have actually some database files... and the file format i have given in File1. What I have to do is... i have to correct those tid.setnr entries and after correction i have load that database file into system. 9/10 entries can be done manually but there are some files which have 1000 entries. I have implemented your solution only for two and that has been done succeessfully. But stucked in those huge files. Thanks a lot again. Tomorrow I will try your solution and tell you the result. Thanks for your quick response.

Comment: Hi Scott...I have slightly modified and used it in my system. Actually what was happening, system was giving me error (--i illegal option) after running this command split --lines=180 "$tmpfile" . So I just used only split -lines=180 "$tmpfile" (File was 1550 lines, i.e 775 tid.setnr entries). But the file was splitted into two parts one was 1000 lines (default) and another was 550 lines. Again system was giving "too many line numbers" error. I used this command, split -l 180 "$tmpfile" tmpF.  It spillted into 9 files (tmpFaa... tmpFai). First 8 files were 180 lines and last file has 110 line.

Comment: After running final sed command on that tmpF files... I got the desired output. Thanks all for cooperating me. It has helped me a lot. I want another help. I want those tmpF (In your answer, its xaa, xab, xac, xad... xae) files to run in loop (For ex. n numbers tmpF files) instead of running sed command manually, (sed -f xab modified_file1aa > modified_file1ab) . Could you please help me how to use loop?

Comment: That's exactly what my last three code blocks are.  You can put the very last one, for example, all on one line as: `for f in "$prefix"*; do sed -i -f "$f" file1; done`.

Comment: Could you please explain me in details... I have 10 or more files (xaa xab xac.... xak)... Then how to use for loop to make the final file at a time using sed?

Comment: What’s the problem?  You could have 676 files (`xaa`, `xab`, `xac`, …, `xzz` = 26×26) and `for f in x*` would cause `$f` to loop through them all.  If you really have no idea what’s going on, I suggest that you do some independent research on the shell and how to script — there’s ***way*** too much information for me to hand-feed it to you.  The ultimate reference is the shell man page — type `man sh` or `man bash` — but that’s probably *not* a good place to start.  Trying to learn scripting from the shell man page  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  is like trying to learn to drive by reading a car’s owner’s manual.  Search the Internet.  I just found [this shell scripting tutorial](http://steve-parker.org/sh/sh.shtml) that appears, at first glance, not to be terrible.  (I’ve never heard of it before, and I haven’t done more than glance at it, so I offer no guarantees.)  You might want to skip to [Chapter 7. Loops](http://steve-parker.org/sh/loops.shtml).  Or you can search this site and [su].  However, beware [Sturgeon’s law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturgeon's_law).

Comment: The problem w/ `split` here is that the user is on a Solaris system and *too many line-numbers* is referring to the nonsense argument `--lines` - which is [not POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/). And I don't believe `sed`'s `-i` option will work on a Solaris system either. I think probably the asker *might be* a ***glutton for punishment*** after all.

Comment: @Scott i need a help. My file2 now changed a little bit,  
.tid.info := 234
.tid.setnr := 1254     
.tid.info := 2123           
.tid.setnr := 9056
I have changed it to, egrep -n "tid.info|tid.setnr" file1 | while IFS=: read n junk. But i think there must little change in printf command, because i am not getting the output ($tmpfile) of these lines tid.info. Only tid.setnr lines were printed with line numbers in my tmpfile. please suggest

Comment: Rule #1 of debugging: If something complicated doesn't work, break it apart into pieces until you figure out where the failure is.  So what's the output from `egrep -n "tid.info|tid.setnr" file1`?  Maybe it would be better if you [edited](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/207893/edit) your question to show this (perhaps as a new section, at the bottom); comments are not a good place to display multi-line commands or data.

Comment: I was doing my correction before only for the tid.setnr now I want to correct tid.info and tid.setnr at a time in file1 from file2. The total answer given by you was very much helpful and it's working. I have edited my question (file2 part). Just added (tid.info) part. @Scott I think the total thing will be same as you suggested but some small change needed in the first part of you answer for the newly addition. PLease suggest

Comment: "the total thing will be same as you suggested"  Yes, I agree.  "but some small change needed"  I don't see why.  **What's the output from `egrep -n "tid.info|tid.setnr" file1`?**  What's the output from `egrep -n "tid.info|tid.setnr" file1 | while IFS=: read n junk; do IFS= read -r line <&3  ||  break; printf "%sc%s\n%s\n" "$n" '\' "$line"; done`?

Comment: 12:tid.info:=64 13:tid.setnr:=1225 21:tid.info:=76 22:tid.setnr:=5625 It was showing me this output. But in my $tmpfile, it was not giving me the output I required. It was printing only tid.setnr part with line numbers in $tmpfile. I want both the lines tid.info and tid.setnr. SO that I can correct in my output file. Better you suggest how to do it. I just showed you in my comment what I have tried. @Scott

Comment: @Scott Please suggest how to solve it. I have already modified.

Answer (score 4):

With GNU sed's R command:

```
sed -e 's/^#.tid.setnr :=.*//;tA;b;:A;R file2' -e 'd' file1
```

Comment: You've made it unnecessarily complicated. `sed '/^#\.tid\.setnr/{R file2` (Enter)
`d}' file1` seems to be good enough.

Comment: Thank you. Or with GNU sed: `sed -e '/^#.tid.setnr/{R file2' -e 'd}' file1`

Comment: Wow!  I had no idea that `{` and `}` could be broken apart into separate *scripts* (separate `-e` arguments) like that.  It's not clear from the documentation.  Is that also a GNU extension?

Comment: @G-Man: A few weeks ago I came across it by a typo. sed (/usr/bin/sed, /usr/xpg4/bin/sed and GNU's /usr/bin/gsed) from Solaris 11 can separate scripts, too.

Comment: @G-Man - It's [specified behavior](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/sed.html): *Multiple `-e` and `-f` options may be specified. All commands shall be added to the script in the order specified, regardless of their origin...* and *The application shall not present a **script** that violates the restrictions of a text file except that the final character need not be a `\n`ewline*.  In most cases you use the null read at the tail of an `-e` arg to represent a newline - like for delimiting `w`rite files or `[aic]`. It usually won't work in an `s///` though.

Answer (score 1):

```
{   sed '/^#\.tid\.setnr/!d;=;g;G' |
    paste  -d'c\\\n' - - - ./addfile
}   <./mainfile | sed -f - ./mainfile
```

It just prepends the relevant line numbers from *./mainfile* to each line in *./addfile* as separated by the command string `c\` and a *<newline>* before passing the results onto another `sed` as a script for editing *./mainfile*. Given your example data, the script generated looks like:

```
13c\
#.tid.setnr := 1254              <--- (I want to put this number in file1 in place of 1225)
22c\
#.tid.setnr := 9056              <--- (I want to put this number in file1 in place of 5625)
```

...which instructs `sed` to `c`hange lines *13* and *22* of its output to match the appended lines for each command.

Comment: same error is coming. "too many line numbers" @mikeserv

Answer (score 0):

I am found of perl.  This script is a crude one that seems to solve the problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#
use strict;

# subroutine to load a test file into an array
sub load{
   my $file = shift;
   open my $in, "<", $file or die "unable to open $file : $!";
   my @data = <$in>;
   chomp @data;
   foreach (@data) { s/\cM//g;}
   return @data;
}


my $file1 = shift || die "usage: $0 [file1] [file2]\n";
my @file1_data = &load($file1);
my $file2 = shift || die "usage: $0 [file1] [file2]\n";
my @file2_data = &load($file2);

my $i = 0;
foreach( @file1_data )
{
    if( $i < @file2_data ) 
    {
        my @s = split / /, $file2_data[$i];
        if( @s )
        {
            if( /^$s[0]/ )
            {
            $_ = $file2_data[$i++];
            }
        }
    }
    print "$_\n";
```