# How to write data one by one from tmp files to the final output file using for loop?

Tags: command-line, text-processing, sed, awk

I have two tmp files named `tmp1` and `tmp2` which contains some lines.
tmp1 file,

```
1c\  
datafile no. 23  
2c\  
datafile is ok
```

tmp2 file,

```
3c\  
datafile no. 24  
4c\  
datafile is ok
```

I have a file (named `wrong_file`) which entries I want to correct from tmp files

```
datafile no. 32  
datafile is ok  
datafile no. 42  
datafile is ok
```

My output file (`modified_file`) will be like,

```
datafile no. 23  
datafile is ok  
datafile no. 24  
datafile is ok
```

I want use for loop which will run until the last tmp file and write data from tmp files to final file (Output) instead doing it manually.

I have tried,

```
sed -f tmp1 wrong_file > file1  
sed -f tmp2 file1 > modified_file
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can just do:

```
cat ./tmp[12] | sed -f - ./wrong_file >outfile
```

At least, that will not cause any issues if all of `sed`'s script instructions are specific to line number. There's no need to apply the scripts separately - you can chain them all together and run the script at once.

That you have to do this at all, though, is indicative of duplicated work. [Here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/207946/52934) is a copy of a `sed` script which would avoid writing any of those tempfiles in the first place and simply scan input for the lines which need changing before passing all of the script in a stream to the final `sed` in one go:

```
{   sed '/^#\.tid\.setnr/!d;=;g;G' |
    paste  -d'c\\\n' - - - ./addfile
}   <./mainfile | sed -f - ./mainfile
```

Its output is not identical to your sample data here because it is tailored to the samples you provided in the [other question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/207893/52934). But it avoids writing out the modification scripts at all and sends all editing commands to a `sed` process which can take action immediately.

In general you can consider that a `sed` process is just as ready to handle its script input in all of the ways it might also be ready to handle its edit content input.-

Comment: cat ./tmp[12] means tmp1 and tmp2. Is it? I want my system to count tmp files and write it to the final file. Then what will be my command? Is it cat ./tmp[*] | sed -f - ./wrong_file >outfile

Comment: @Nainita - yeah, your shell should expand the `[12]` glob to two arguments. I would just use it for `sed` like `sed -f ./tmp1 -f ./tmp2 infile >outfile` but I just wanted to show that you can string any number together - and I thought it might be possible that you could have more than two eventually.

Comment: Suppose I dont know how many tmp file has been created and I want to write those tmp files data like this way. Then what will be the command? Should I have to put * instead of [12] in cat ./tmp[*] ?

Comment: @Nainita - you might, but be sure your globs are restrictive enough *not* to include any `sed` commands you don't want, is all. But yes, `*` will work as well as `[num-num]`, it's just that it is more inclusive.

Comment: @Nainita - by the way, I'm fairly sure I know where those came from, too. If you had used the answer I offered to that other question, you probably would not have ever needed to create any tempfiles at all.

Comment: Actually I needed to create tmp files because using sed command it was giving me "too may line numbers" error at the time of writing in the final file. So I have created tmp files using "split" command. Now I want these tmp files to write lines one by one to my final file.

Comment: @Nainita - I read that, but I have to ask, did you actually try my answer there? You're doing the same thing now that my answer there did all of the while when you `cat files* | sed -f -`...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24763/discussion-between-nainita-and-mikeserv).