# Replace pattern with line from file using awk/sed

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

I have a file `first.html` which contains the following code:

```
<tr>
<td class="headerValue">One</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="headerValue">Two</td>
</tr>
```

Now I have another file `second.txt` which contains some values like:

```
hahaha
hehehe
```

I want to replace the value in each occurence of "headerValue" with the value from the second file.

Eg. after replacement `first.html` will become

```
<tr>
<td class="headerValue">hahaha</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="headerValue">hehehe</td>
</tr>
```

The data from file second.txt is unrelated to the data from file first.txt

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use sed to modify a file line by line?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/207893/80216)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible answer.  I used perl though.
It does not check for blank lines in the second file.
And the substitution is hard coded.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#
use strict;

# subroutine to load a test file into an array
sub load{
   my $file = shift;
   open my $in, "<", $file or die "unable to open $file : $!";
   my @data = <$in>;
   chomp @data;
   foreach (@data) { s/\cM//g;}
   return @data;
}


my $first = shift || die "usage: $0 [first] [second]\n";
my @first_data = &load($first);
my $second = shift || die "usage: $0 [first] [second]\n";
my @second_data = &load($second);

my $i = 0;
foreach( @first_data )
{
    if( s{(<td class="headerValue">)(.*?)(</td>)}{$1$second_data[$i]$3} )
    {
        $i++;
    }
    print "$_\n";
}
```